# Изменить стиль другого элемента при клике

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть три ссылки, при клике на каждую из которых подсвечивается соответствующая строка таблицы

```
<div>
    <a href='#n1'>Первый</a>
    <a href='#n2'>Второй</a>
    <a href='#n3'>Третий</a>
</div>

<table id='content'>
    <tr id="n1"><td>1.</td><td>Первая</td><td>Строка</td></tr>
    <tr id="n2"><td>1.</td><td>Вторая</td><td>Строка</td></tr>
    <tr id="n3"><td>1.</td><td>Третья</td><td>Строка</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div a').click(function() {
        var clickId = $(this).attr('href');
        $(clickId).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div a').click(function(){
        $('div a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active')
    })
});
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике по строке таблицы также менялся стиль и строки и ссылки.

**Обновление**

Пример [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/SDJKQ/26/).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div a, #content tr').on('click', function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('div a:eq(' + index + '), #content tr:eq(' + index + ')')
      .addClass('active')
      .siblings()
      .removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
#content .active {
  background: #ff0000;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #333
}
a.active {
  background: #333;
  color: #ffffff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href='#n1'>Первый</a>
  <a href='#n2'>Второй</a>
  <a href='#n3'>Третий</a>
</div>

<table id='content'>
  <tr id="n1">
    <td>1.</td>
    <td>Первая</td>
    <td>Строка</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="n2">
    <td>1.</td>
    <td>Вторая</td>
    <td>Строка</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="n3">
    <td>1.</td>
    <td>третья</td>
    <td>Строка</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень коротко и, главное, работает. Но не совсем так, если строки будут вразброс либо будет какая-то строка пропущена, нужно, чтобы подсвечивалась строка с определенным id.
Например:
при клике на ссылку <a href='#n3'>Третий</a> должен измениться класс у строки <tr id="n3"><td>1.</td><td>третья</td><td>Строка</td></tr>, даже если она будет второй или первой по счету.
http://jsfiddle.net/SDJKQ/29/

Comment: Все, сам сделал, правда получилось немного длинно.

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pagecontainer div, .content_part tr').click(function() {
        var clickId = $(this).attr('title');
        $(clickId).addClass('active-part').siblings().removeClass('active-part');
  $(this).addClass('active-part');
  $('.pagecontainer div').click(function(){$('.pagecontainer div').removeClass('active-part');$(this).addClass('active-part')});
  $('.content_part tr').click(function(){$('.content_part tr').removeClass('active-part');$(this).addClass('active-part')});
    });

});

Comment: @anti1994, в таком случае будет лучше связать ссылки и строки с помощью data-атрибутов - http://jsfiddle.net/SDJKQ/30/