# js при клике на элемент с id изменить класс двух других

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток
нужен аналог табов
функция, которая при клике на ссылке присвоит всем дивам класс hidden (скроет их через display:none;)
а потом сделает видимым только нужным див

Примерно я вижу как это сделать

по клике пробежаться по документу, найти все блоки с классом myblock и addclass hidden
потом  найти блок с айди divcontent+переданный в функцию параметр и установить ему класс show
но немного хромают знания

```js
function functabs(number) {


  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('myblock');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].classList.add("hidden");
  }
  document.getElementById('divcontent' + number).classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById('divcontent' + number).classList.add("show");
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: blok;
  background-color: red;
}

.show2 {
  display: blok;
  background-color: green;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- здесь ccылки, которые должны передавать в функцию номер видимого дива -->
<a onclick="functabs('1')">текст ссылки</a><br>
<a onclick="functabs('2')">текст ссылки</a><br>
<a onclick="functabs('3')">текст ссылки</a><br>
<a onclick="functabs('4')">текст ссылки</a>
<!-- здесь блоки, которые должны менять классы -->
<br><br><br>

<div class="show2">это не скрывать!
</div>

<div class="myblock show" id="divcontent1">divcontent1
</div>
<div class="myblock hidden" id="divcontent2">divcontent2
</div>
<div class="myblock hidden" id="divcontent3">divcontent3
</div>
<div class="myblock hidden" id="divcontent4">divcontent4
</div>
```

Comment: а потом сделает видимым только нужным див? если блоки скрыты

Comment: @soledar10 да, removeclass hidden и addclass show у нужного блока

Comment: как определить нужный див? если эти дивы скрыты

Comment: @soledar10 нашел что-то похожее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356440/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5?rq=1

Comment: @soledar10 а если opacity использовать 1-0 вместо дисплей? или позиционировать к примеру left: 10000px?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если простым JavaScript кодом, то можно так. Получим коллекцию элементов по имени тэга [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), нам нужны div-теги. Затем в цикле через свойство [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) с помощью методов `add` и `remove` добавляем и удаляем классы из элементов. Пример кода:

```js
function functabs(number) {
  var textmess = "Давайте div " + number + " покажем";
  console.log(textmess);

  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  // var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('myblock'); // или так
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].classList.add("hidden");
  }
  document.getElementById('divcontent' + number).classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById('divcontent' + number).classList.add("show");
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: blok;
  background-color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="functabs('1')">текст ссылки 1</a><br>
<a onclick="functabs('2')">текст ссылки 2</a><br>
<a onclick="functabs('3')">текст ссылки 3</a><br>
<a onclick="functabs('4')">текст ссылки 4</a>
<!-- здесь блоки, которые должны менять классы -->
<br><br><br>
<div class="myblock show" id="divcontent1">divcontent 1
</div>
<div class="myblock show" id="divcontent2">divcontent 2
</div>
<div class="myblock show" id="divcontent3">divcontent 3
</div>
<div class="myblock show" id="divcontent4">divcontent 4
</div>
```

Про добавление и удаление класса можно ознакомиться тут: [Добавление и удаление класса элемента по клику на кнопку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658494/189339). Там есть пример и с jQuery и JavaScript.

Comment: Спасибо! то что доктор прописал!))

Comment: а если в будет конструкция с вложенными блоками?
оно и их поменяет?
может через getElementsByClassName лучше?

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк, если будет один див вложен в другой, при этом вы будете менять класс у вложенного дива на `show`, а у родительского будет класс `hidden`, то вне зависимости от того, как вы получите элементы, вложенный див не отобразится. Так как родительский скрыт. Посмотрите сюда: [Как показать дочерние элементы, если родительский элемент скрыт с помощью display: none?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658316/189339)

Comment: я  на  document.getElementById('divcontent' + number).classList.remove("hidden"); не обратил внимание. думал что оно скроет все дивы на странице (а там много нужных) и выведет только требуемый. Сори, не спал всю ночь. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: хотя так и выходит, ведь в цыкле for оно всем дивам из коллекции добавит стиль hidden

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк из вопроса: *функция, которая при клике на ссылке присвоит всем дивам класс hidden*, все так, сначала всем делаем `hidden`, а затем для того, который передан в функцию убираем `hidden` и добавляем класс `show`. Затем по переданному номеру дива берем див и он будет отображен.

Comment: да, мой косяк. ТЗ неточно сформулировал. я могу заменить var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); на var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('myblock'); и получу желаемое.